# Need to group LINQ to Entities Results

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Here is my code:

```
var context = new InventoryContext();

var res = from i in context.Inventories
          select new FullInventory
          {
              InventoryID = i.InventoryID,
              ItemModelID = i.ItemModelID,
              ModelName = i.ItemModel.ModelName,
              ...
              Quantity = context.Inventories.Select(x => x.ItemModelID).Count()
          };

return res.ToList();
```

The code I have works great, however the results look like this:

```
   CATEGORY   | MANUFACTURER | MODEL | QUANTITY
1. Hard drive | Dell         | 250GB | 2
2. Hard drive | Dell         | 250GB | 2
```

As you can see, I have 2 entries in the table and since those entries are exactly the same, I would like them to be grouped together. To group them together I need to group by `ItemModelID`, however I still need to put all of the data into a list of `FullInventory` classes.

How can I group my data together while still "selecting" the data into a list of `FullInventory` classes?

Comment: When you say "grouped" together, you mean you want your result set to have just 1 object for the 250GB Dell Hard Drive with Quantity 4?

Comment: KOTJMF: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by that value and then just select out the first item from each group using `let`.

```
var res = from inventory in context.Inventories
          group inventory by inventory.ItemModelID into model
          let i = model.FirstOrDefault()
          select [...]
```

Comment: Well this code does not work. Something is wrong with the group by line, but I will see what I can try and figure out.

Comment: @acbarberi "It doesn't work." isn't helpful.  Does it not compile, does it throw an exception, is the output different than expected, if so, how.  You need to provide details if you want help.

Comment: Well, the code is wrong and no it would not compile. It was underlined in red in Visual Studio. It's OK though because I fixed it.

Comment: @acbarberi Again, details.  What doesn't compile, what's the error, what line is it on, etc.  If you fixed it, what did you fix?

Comment: var res2 = from inventory in context.Inventories
                       group inventory by inventory.ItemModelID into model
                       let i = model.FirstOrDefault()
                       select new FullInventory

Comment: Can't post my own dang answer.

Comment: See original post. Updated to include answer.

Comment: @acbarberi I think it's just some mistake between `SQL syntax` and `LINQ query syntax`, which are very similar.

Comment: @KingKing Actually it's just a result of me virtually always using method syntax, not query syntax, but either way it's just a little typo that's easily fixed.

Comment: Yes, I can understand it. I also always use `method syntax`, very rarely use `query syntax` (if not wanting to say, `never`).

Answer (score 1):

I would attempt the Group By after retrieving the full list with a Lambda expression:

```
 var context = new InventoryContext();

 return (from i in context.Inventories
         select new FullInventory
         {
             InventoryID = i.InventoryID,
             ItemModelID = i.ItemModelID,
             ModelName = i.ItemModel.ModelName,
             ...
             Quantity = context.Inventories.Select(x => x.ItemModelID).Count()
         }).GroupBy(g => g.ItemModelID).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks but this returns an IGroupable and I need an IEnumerable<FullInventory>

Comment: Even though it is an IGroupable, is the returned results set what you were expecting?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Distinct()`

```
return res.Distinct().ToList()
```

Comment: This did not help. I got the same results as before.